# Does a Parent's onAreaTouched Trigger the Child's?

Tags: java, android, andengine

I have a sprite with an attached child right next to it. When touched the image is rotated 180 degrees, but to keep the image in place I only have the parent call rotate. This means that if the child is touched, it calls its parent's rotate. This works fine when the child is touched, but I found that if the parent is touched, then the child's onAreaTouched() is called as well, which then calls the parent's rotate, which undoes the rotate.

I can't find in the code anything that says the children's onAreaTouched() is called when a parent's, but is that what's happening?

Comment: TouchArea is just a simple list maintained by scene, there is no parent-child relationship at all. Your problem may be related to if your touch areas are overlapped (if overlapped, which one is in front of the other) and/or what is the return value in you touch area event hanlder(s)?

Comment: The areas do not overlap. However, how would the return value affect things?

Comment: If child object return false then and only parent objects method get called otherwise only child object touch method executed.

Comment: My code was returning `super.onAreaTouched(_)`, now it just returns true and it works as desired. Thanks! If one of you make an actual answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I consider Scene as a parent object and Rectangle as a child object.

```
Scene mScene = new Scene();
mScene.setOnSceneTouchListener(this);

Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(x,y,width,height){
     public boolean onAreaTouch(){
          if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()){
               return true;
          }
          return false;
     }
};

mScene.registerTouchArea(rectangle);
mScene.attachChile(rectangle);

public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(){
      if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()){
           return true;
      } else if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()){
           return true;
      }
      return false;
}
```

In the above code snippet I write all the basic things those are necessary for understanding this concept. Here rectangle is a child of scene. Rectangle contains area touch with three events action down,move and up. I return true in only action down event so parent object action down event doesn't called.

For all other event of child object I return false, so its parent object perform remaining to action such as move and up action.

If child object return directly true to onAreaTouch method then parent object scene touch method does not call at all. This was a small example through which I tried to explain this concept.